# Curvilinear perspective with Gimp

Tags: gimp, perspective

How could I make a curvilinear perspective with Gimp? I've found out making a linear perspective, but not curvilinear.

My guess was that there were any way to move the single points in the grid, and not just the endpoints.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in perspective, bur it seems difficult to me change it in a 2D space (see [here](http://termespheres.com/6-point-perspective/)). There is a related question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222025/curvilinear-perspective-convert-3d-to-2d)

Comment: @PaoloGibellini - Thanks for the links. I don't know yet how to create a Script-Fu, but I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a tool in Gimp 2.8 (transform grid), that has helped me to do what I wanted. Look at this example:

Original

[image: original]

Tool button:

[image: tool]

Create grid:

[image: create grid]

Transform grid:

[image: transform grid]

In this way, you could achieve giving perspective to linear images.